# Invalid character constant JSON

Tags: java, json

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put('set_boot' : True);
    json.put('synchronous': True),
    json.put('filters',filterList);

    List filterList = new ArrayList();
    filterList.put(6005076802818994A0000000000009DD);

    json.put('volumes':volumeList);

    List volumeList = new ArrayList();
    volumeList.add('*all');

    json.add( 'allow_unsupported': True);
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity( json.toString());
    System.out.println(se);
   }
}
```

---

I am trying to add values to convert into a JSON query like:

```
{
    'set_boot': True,
    'synchronous': True,
    'filters': {
        'host_refs': [u '6005076802818994A0000000000009DD']
    },
    'volumes': ['*all'],
    'allow_unsupported': True
}
```

But Eclipse is giving me error Invalid Character constant
on line

```
json.put('set_boot' : True);
```

I have tried writing a few other words also like

```
json.put('set' : True);
```

But it still gives me the same error.

Comment: `true`, not `True`. ;)

Comment: why 'True' and not 'true'? I see you are adding lots of objects just before you create them. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: What language is this meant to be? Because it's not valid Java...

Comment: I think you should probably put aside your madness ( :-) ) and *learn* Java.

Comment: Sorry everyone if it looks basic but actually I have to convert python to Java :( , so these sort of errors

Comment: In this case you should start with reading about the basics of Java and don' waste your time asking such questions here. That is far too much overhead to reach your goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is meant to be Java, you want:

```
json.put("set_boot", true);
json.put("synchronous", true);
```

(There are similar problems later on.)

Note:

- String literals are in double-quotes, not single-quotes in Java
- You're calling a method with two arguments - use a comma to separate the arguments
- The boolean true value in Java is `true`, not `True`. You could use `"True"` to set a *string* value if you want
- You're trying to use `filterList` before it's declared
- You're trying to call `put` on a `List`, when that method doesn't exist... you meant `add`
- Your literal of `6005076802818994A0000000000009DD` is invalid. Did you mean to use a string literal?

These are all just matters of the Java language, and have nothing to do with JSON in themselves.

Comment: Also `put` isn't a method on `java.util.List` (assuming that's the one he's using) and the `string` variable seems to come from nowhere. Sounds like he just isn't familiar with the syntax/libraries, which his username seems to suggest as well.

Comment: @Brian : Thanks for the funny critical comments. I would try to improve.
Jon Skeet: Thanx a lot sir

Answer (score 1):

Besides your snytax errors in Java, your JSON example is invalid syntax as well. Check it using [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) or other services. It should look like the following:

```
{
    "set_boot": true,
    "synchronous": true,
    "filters": {
        "host_refs": [
            "6005076802818994A0000000000009DD"
        ]
    },
     "volumes": [
        "*all"
    ],
    "allow_unsupported": true
}
```

Comment: Actually that was meant to be in Python and I don't know much about Python. So I forgot changing ' to ".